# How to add additional grouped address to edit and detail view?

Tags: sugarcrm

SugarCRM 6.5 has built in grouped address fields in the Lead Module for the Primary Address and for the Alternate Address that can be used with the Edid and Detail view.  I have been able to add the fields for a third address, but when I add the new address field to the edit view and detail view, it does not show the grouped fields, just a single field.

According to the documentation I can use the customCode option in the Detail View and Edit View definitions, but I have not been able to succesfully get this working.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You must give a prefix for all the address fields like 'billing' or 'primary'. Then your address fields would be of the form:
billing_address_street
billing_address_city
billing_address_state
billing_address_postalcode
billing_address_country

In Editview you can show this as a single grouped address by adding the below code in editviewdefs. Replace 'billing' by whatever prefix you have used.

```
array (
  'name' => 'billing_address_street',
  'hideLabel' => true,
  'type' => 'address',
  'displayParams' => 
  array (
    'key' => 'billing',
    'rows' => 2,
    'cols' => 30,
    'maxlength' => 150,
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a custom address field that has been added through studio, then sugarcrm won't automatically group the address fields, because the field names end in `_c`. This is a reported bug: https://web.sugarcrm.com/support/issues/cbb00e33-351b-5448-2e5f-4eaf7551f347

There is a blog post here explaining how to work around it:

http://www.profilingsolutions.com/archive/custom-address-fields/

(basically - remove the `_c` suffix from the created address fields in the database and fix up the vardefs).